# Does duplicating images in training dataset improves accuracy in CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, conv-neural-network

I am using a leaf dataset to train CNN. My dataset contains 20k images and 185 classes. 
I want to train my CNN using more data. Just assuming that might improve the test accuracy. Correct me if wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The model is trained on the same dataset in an epoch. So, it sees the image once every epoch. To increase the model's efficiency, you may try Data Augmentation instead of repeating samples within an epoch.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Thank You. Will try doing that!